# CiviReport - Can Report Titles be sorted?

Tags: civireport

I've created about 20 reports under Event Reports but Civi seems to sort the report titles in order of creation. Is there way to have the report titles sorted alphabetically?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is.

I would get around this by creating a new top level menu item called "XYZ reports" (assuming you work for company XYZ).

Then you can add major categories so that you can group reports as you want. (I have finance, membership, fundraising,training and marketing  as my categories/parents for the reports.) Once you have assigned a report to the appropriate parent menu you have complete control over the order of the reports via Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Navigaiton Menu.

Comment: Thanks JoAnne, I did use your suggestion as a work around. My first thought was to simply use bookmarks, which is fine for me but not anyone else. Although surprised this much effort was required to sort the report titles, the solution did work and, more importantly for me, was well accepted by active users of the site. Whew!

Comment: Yes this works nicely and also means that you get the menus as a submenu rather than going through another page. A bit of a pain to have to copy all the report URLs but worth it.